# Need to Release PDF File From IronOCR in C#

Tags: c#, process, io, ocr

I'm using IronOCR to extract text from pdf's placed in a folder using C#.  I have a process running that waits for a pdf to be placed into a folder and then runs the code below.

```
var ocr = new IronTesseract();
using (var input = new OcrInput(pdfFileToProcess))
{
    input.Deskew();
    input.Binarize();
    var ocrResult = ocr.Read(input);
    textFromOCRResult = ocrResult.Text;
}
```

An example pdfFileToProcess could be d:\TestOCR\C01.pdf.

When this runs it works great once. However when I put the same or another PDF in that folder i get the following error.  It's like IronOCR won't let go of the PDF file.

```
System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file 'D:\TestOCR\C01.pdf' because it is being used by another process.'
```

This error is pointing to the code line

```
using (var input = new OcrInput(pdfFileToProcess))
```

Comment: You should include more information about the pdfFileToProcess and how that is handled. Looks like OcrInput class provided in IronOcr has several constructors. Is pdfFileToProcess an image? Bytes? Since OcrInput implements IDisposable (since you use it when calling using) I doubt the problem is there unless the library has a large easily found defect. I would suspect the problem lies in your own code when reading pdfFileToProcess from source. Are you using a using statement there?

Comment: @AnthonyG. pdfFileToProcess is a pointer to a PDF file that is passed by my process when it essentially watches the folder. pdfFileToProcess = Path.GetDirectoryName(enumerator.Current) + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(enumerator.Current);